# Associate a Case with Multiple Locations

Tags: lightning-aura-components, multi-select, junction-object

I need to give users the ability to create a case that's associated with multiple locations. There's currently a Master-Detail relationship between Account and Location. When a user is creating a case I want to display all the locations on the case's account and give the user the ability to multi select locations to associate them with the case. Is this possible and how can I accomplish this? When I originally built this the requirement was to associate a case with one location so I created a lookup. Now there's a requirement where under 1 circumstance a case can be associated with multiple locations.

Comment: as per my understanding , since you need to associate a case with multiple locations ,it can be accomplished with a sort of junction object  with lookup to both case and location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case has an object called `CaseContactRole` which is a junction object between Contact and Case. This allows you to have multiple contacts related to the Case. You'll want to do the same with `Account Location`. Once you create a junction object called `CaseLocationRole` (or similar), you'll be able to create a related list to put on the Case detail page and add a component to hold it.

Comment: I couldn't find CaseContactRole but I found OpportunityContactRole which has two lookups one to Opportunity and the other to Contact. I created something similar for CaseLocation and I added it to the Case layout. When I tried to add a new record the lookup was returning all the Locations and not the ones associated with that case's account. I tried to add a filter to the lookup but case account wasn't an option. I created a text formula field with the Case Account but when I tried to use that field the lookup wasn't returning any results.

Comment: was I supposed to create the junction table for Account Location or Case Location? I did it for Case Location.

Answer (score 0):

I created a relationship between the junction table and Accounts as well and I used a dual list box on a custom component to allow multi select.